# Amazon s3cmd ls

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have a requirement to list the file from an Amazon S3 location:

```
BUCKET= "s3://static.abc.com"
s3cmd ls --recursive $BUCKET/colorpics/*/640/
```

The `colorpics` directory contains multiple sub-directories for years like:

```
2013
2014
2015
2016
```

So the `ls` command should list the images for all the years dynamically and it should list only from next level sub-directory `/640/`.

If I give `/*/` it works when the file system is mounted.  But when I try to list from the bucket it fails.

Is there anyway I can achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the file system is mounted"?

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon S3 API can return the content of a bucket based on a prefix such as `s3://static.abc.com/colorpics/`, however it cannot have a wildcard mid-pattern. This is probably why `s3cmd` cannot provide that functionality.

By the way, these days it is better to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has a matching `aws s3 ls` command.